# Empty black screen after on virtual machine

Tags: 14.04

My ubuntu 14 virtual box virtual machine shut down because of cut in power supply to machine.

Now I am getting black screen ,I have restarted and shunt down machine many times.

But no result.

Please guide.

-Thanks
Shahab

Comment: well, you´re not having the problem on the host OS so just install a new VM :)

Answer (score 0):

Um well there a quite a few things that could be going wrong here.
I have had this issue before a few times and never caused by the 
same thing.

First try turning on the box, in the menu, Machine > Reset.
I have had luck with this before.

What is your host os, Ubuntu.. Windows? 
If ubuntu, you may need to reinstall kernel drivers.

Lastly check if the boot medium is still attached:
Goto Settings > Storage Look if "Controller:SATA" is Empty.

Comment: Hi,

I tried Machine > Reset option but no result.

Settings > Storage Looks fine.

I have my appliations on lampp (xampp) if I install new virtual machine then all 

my appliations can not be migrated because I can not access xampp from URL to take database backup using phpmyadmin

I can not update software or kernal no access to terminal only black white screen coming.

Any Idea?

-Thanks
Shahab

Comment: Huh. When you boot up the box is all you see black, or does it show some boot screens before, bios, grub, etc? Did you push updates on the host or guest before the power failure?

Comment: No. I have not push any update. Sometimes I can see boot loader with options like memory test and other. I tried all but no result.Thanks Shahab